# Reverse number function in python loops when if statement is added

Tags: python, numbers

```
def number_from_other_side(n):
    k = 1 
    a = 1 
    length = 0
    sum_next_numbers = 0
    while n // a != 0:
        length += 1 
        a = a * 10
    length -= 1
    number_1 = n // (10**(length))
    #if length == 0:
        #return number_1
    while length - k > 0:
        next_number_1 = n // 10**(length - k) 
        next_number_2 = ( next_number_1 - 10**k * (next_number_1 // 10) ) * 10**k
        sum_next_numbers += next_number_2     
        k += 1
    last_number = (n - (n // 10) * 10) * 10**length
    reverse_number = sum_next_numbers + number_1 + last_number
   
    return reverse_number
```

This is my code to reverse an integer number. I must not use strings. This is how I've done it. It kind of works except if the number n is only one number, then if I add an if statement, it never compiles.

The if statement, that I want to put in is in comment section (#).

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong here. The code compiles if I remove/comment the if statement.
The code just runs and never ends with the if statement. Same as in an infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "it never compiles"? Do you get an error? I don't see anything obviously wrong with those lines.

Comment: You don't "compile" python, per se.  It's interpreted/parsed, that is, it's ran line by line when it's executed.  If there's a syntax error, then the code may not run.  Or if there is a runtime error, it'll run until it gets to that point.

Comment: Okay sorry, it just runs and never ends. Same as in an infinite loop.

Comment: You set `sum_of_digits`, but never use it.  Then you use `+=` with `sum_next_numbers`, which was never defined.

Comment: Most implementations of Python, including the reference CPython implementation, do involve a compilation step.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have rewritten it wrong. In my program it is correct, still, this isn't the problem here. The problem is why it doesn't work with the if statement.

Comment: @BiliDebili What value do you pass to `number_from_other_side()` that causes the "infinite loop?"

Comment: for n = 3, it returns 6 without if statement. If I add an if statement to get 3, then it loops...

Comment: @Bili Simply adding that `if` won't cause an infinite loop, since all it does is allow for an early exit. You must have changed something else at the same time.

Comment: @BiliDebili I'm not seeing an infinite loop.  [Demo here](https://tio.run/##dZLLboMwEEX3/orpznYUBZpdpOZXEFVMQYQhMiaPr6fDODamabxAfty5Z@aKy8PVPe6n6WQqwLH7NraobN8VvatpOzQnI1EdBNBq4Qty4G25bM8Gf1xN54yPw9gVaO6u8GZDfLjVzdkAwm5H1R90600Ti030DIgSNORZitmShs/PXnNSsafMM62lVynFkqaKza1w1rjRYnRIugsQGvWYViQDLcQEOFco@Ff@SXL5x2DLtS0NJ9cP7KpA8dikiI4vqVJWa8q8orzlLH1u5RBUcydIcIkBpONXaz@J8AFdiWGWslf8kv8mRYjQxTPjtZMQF9ugk2/@s71S0/QL)

Comment: Exactly, what happens if you compile my code. Does it also loop if you uncomment the if statement in it ?

Comment: @BiliDebili The demo link I posted has the `if` uncommitted, and the code runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding or removing the `if` doesn't seem to generate a different syntax error. However, I think you're over complicating things - you could iterate over the digits by extracting a the last digit with the `%` operator, and then (integer) divide the number to advance to the next digit:

```py
def number_from_other_side(n):
    result = 0;
    while n > 0:
        digit = n % 10
        result = result * 10 + digit
        n //= 10

    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is the need to complete such a simple task. It can done by a simple while loop.

```
n=12345
new=0
while n:
    new *= 10
    new += n% 10
    n   = n//10
print(new)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it runs on an infinite loop is because if it is single digit then length is one. Now in the while loop in line 6  ==>  *n : {1 to 9}* and a is declared as 1.
So in the first loop
`n//1 = n` In the 2nd loop `n//10=n` then `n//100=n` and so on causing an infinite loop.

so add the if statement before this while loop

Comment: I'm running the code in my head, so I could be wrong, but the `length -= 1` does look like it would cause `length` to be 0 with a single digit of `n`.

Comment: `9 // 1` gives a non-zero answer, so the loop is entered and it will increment `length`, then `9 // 10` will be zero so the loop will exit, then `length` is decremented back to 0.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad actually tried to find the cause of the infinite loop I mistook `//` for `%`. Sorry if this mislead anyone. Actually the original code even though a bit too complicated works fine in my PC.